# Do semi-complex material node groups considerably slow down Blender?

Tags: materials, node-editor, groups

I've put together several node groups for the purposes of color correction, falloff, and other various utilities. I'm wondering though what kind of impact this will have on my scenes if my materials are utilizing a lot of node groups.

I like to use my falloff and color correction nodes a lot because it helps save a lot of time, but I am concerned I am unnecessarily complicating the node tree for my materials.

So, I guess this is kind of a broad question, but what kind of impact on speed can I expect when using several node groups? Am I worrying unnecessarily?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It honestly depends on your device. My MacBook air (which has around the same performance as my windows 8 machine) does slow down when I use semi-complex material nodes, but this is just a slight but noticeable drop in framerate. A good workaround though is to just make sure your viewport camera is a good distance from your object.  This keeps your framerate reasonably high. But no, I wouldn't say considerable.

Comment: Interesting read, relevant to cycles also:  https://devtalk.blender.org/t/eevee-shader-compilation/5573

Comment: @AllenSimpson Great info, thank you.

Comment: @AllenSimpson similar optimizations (cycles) in [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/optimizations/nodes.html#shader-nodes) also, there was a paper about it somewhere I think, but I can't place where I saw it at the moment.

Comment: @Timaroberts ah, this is a good page.  alleviates a lot of concern